# Cannot log in to the MySQL server error when I try to connect with phpmyadmin ampps

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, ampps

I execute the below command :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Its suddenly stop my phpmyadmin panel and give me the following error every time:

**Can not log in to the MySQL server**

My configuration setting listed is below in config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123456';
```

Still, I can not able to login into my Phpmyadmin panel.

Comment: you've set the password to 'password' (most securely), but you config lists '123456'

Comment: with 'cannot long in' what error does it give?

Comment: Its working fine now...thanks @danblack